# Why does DomSanitizer not work for string value?

Tags: angular, typescript, iframe, cross-site, angular-dom-sanitizer

**Goal**: Send string variable from Angular application(typesript) to iFrame living on another server so it can be used in a conditional

**Question**: How do I use DomSanitizer for a variable specifically?

Documentation states types are: HTML, Style, Script, Url. What if I just want to send a plain string variable? Documentation is not clear about this.

SecurityContext shows the same https://angular.io/api/core/SecurityContext . I tried script. I also tried sanitize method but it needs securitycontext.

I tried using Script but I get the error:
Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)
    at DomSanitizerImpl.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DomSanitizerImpl.sanitize

I read (http://g.co/ng/security#xss) and (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#Security_concerns) as well as other articles about domsanitizer, postmessage, Angular lifecycles, etc
I have tried placing the code in different areas of the file, including onload etc.

chat.component.html:

```
<div class="iframe-container"> 
    <iframe id="iframe_chatui" src="{{ chatURL }}/loading.html" class="chatiframe" allow="microphone; camera"></iframe>
</div>
```

chat.component.ts:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {        
        this.safeScript = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(this.localeId);
        let frame = document.getElementById('iframe_chatui');           
    }
```

when I add the following, I get error: Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of null

```
let frame = document.getElementById('iframe_chatui') as HTMLIFrameElement;       
frame.contentWindow.postMessage(this.localeId, '*');
```

Comment: Why would you sanitize a string? That doesn't make sense. String is a string.

Comment: Because I get the XSS error which poiints to documentation which tells me to Sanitize it. How do I not get the error if I don't sanitize?

Comment: You should sanitize an URL. `const toSanitize = chatURL+"/loading.html"`

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry, I don't think I'm understanding why sanitize the url when its the value I want to pass, however I just applied what you said, but, I am still unable to postMessage to the iframe. No matter where I place it I get: Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of null

Answer (score 0):

Try bypassing the angular security by using the *bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl*. Then use this value from the function to call the iframe.

**But be very careful, you are bypassing the inbuilt angular security mechanism**. If you trust the URL, making sure that it comes only from your source then you can use the function.

Here is the link to the angular documentation:
https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl

I do recomment reading about the URL attacks that can happen on the owasp website. Make sure your url passes the regex mentioned in the following link:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Validation_Regex_Repository